# ASP.NET MVC: Redirecting back to page when no parameter is provided in Firefox 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox-3

I'm trying to do exactly the same thing as detailed in this question:

[ASP.NET MVC: Redirecting back to page when no parameter is given to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272454/asp-net-mvc-redirecting-back-to-page-when-no-parameter-is-given-to-url)

Here's my code:

```
public ActionResult Details(long? id)
{
    if (!id.HasValue)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    Models.Track track = Models.Track.GetTrack(id.Value);
    if (track == null)
        return View("NotFound");
    else
        return View("Details", track);
}
```

However, when I call `RedirectToAction("Index")` and I'm viewing the page in Firefox 3, the page hangs.  It redirects fine in IE7.

Are there any known issues with RedirectToAction in Firefox 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.  Open Firefox.  Type "about:config" in the address bar.  Hit enter.  Accept the warning. Then look for:

network.dns.disableIPv6

set it to true by double-clicking the line.  Try your web app now.  Does that work?

Comment: Yup, that seemed to do the trick. Are you able to offer any insight as to what's happening here?  Many thanks.

Comment: According to some articles on the web, there is a problem with looking up DNS on localhost.. probably because you are behind a proxy?  I am at work and I used to get this problem. I think it has to with how the network is configured.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how your urls are configured but maybe you are in a recursive loop? That you are continously redirecting to the same page?

Comment: If I were doing this, surely I would observe the same behaviour in IE7?